# Xcode cannot connect to member center

Tags: xcode, xcode6, iphone-developer-program

When I want to connect my developer account in xCode 6, I receive this message : "An error occurred while communicating with the member center."

Someone know what is the problem ? Someone can help me ? Thanks !

Comment: is your account credential correct?

Comment: @ShamsAhmed Yeah ! I could connected with xCode 5

Comment: @Mindsers Interesting how even though I provided the correct answer first, you still picked another asnwer that was provided 2 days later (and said exactly the same thing that I did before) as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same message. In my case, my firstname (Björn) has an special character 'ö'. I changed it in my apple id profile to Bjoern and then it worked and i cloud submit to app store.

Comment: OK! Thanks. My name contain special character too ! ALL informations in the developer account must not contain any spacial character.

Answer (score 12):

It might also be that there's a maintenance going on and the server is temporarily down. There's a [system status website for developers](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) indicating scheduled maintenances and temporary downtimes. Also check the Apple Developer Member Center website for this:

[image]

Then just sit back and brew yourself some hot cocoa.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening with accounts that have any special character like "í" or "ç" in their name. If you edit your Apple ID and remove any special characters it will work.

I hope this gets fixed before the official release.

Comment: I got the same problem with the Xcode 6 GM build. I filed bug report 18288974, would be great if you could file a bug report too.

Comment: @vegidio I haven't any special character in my account's name. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Paul I filed bug report 18287866.

Comment: Bug report 18301632 filed. Thanks @vegidio for your hint: my last name is mutilated, but Xcode works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that is being investigated - thank you for your bug reports. The issue is not in Xcode itself, but rather in services that it communicates with, so it cannot be addressed by an update to Xcode. -- Apple Support

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I had 3 appleID's in the account panel.
2 of them were old expired appleID's.
I removed them to keep only my active appleID.
And then the connection was succesful
Hope this will help

Comment: But I have only one apple ID and it's not expired... Thanks for your help.